# Stack size in QThread

Tags: c++, qt, stack, qthread

What is the maximal default stack size when using **QThread** in **QT5** and **C++**? I have a **QVector** in my thread and I am calling `myvector.append()` method, and I`m interested how big my vector can be. I found `uint QThread::stackSize() const` method which returns Stack size, but only if it was previously changed by method `setStackSize()`, but what is the default Stack Size?

Comment: The internals of a vector should be on the "heap" so you basically have a limit of the largest single block you could create in the system ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack size only plays are role if you are compiling a 32 bit application *and* you're allocating the storage for your buffer explicitly on the stack. Just using an automatic `QVector` or `std::vector` instance doesn't allocate any large buffers on the stack - you'd need to use a custom allocator for that.

IIRC in 64 bit applications, the memory is laid out such that you won't ever run out of stack space for any reasonable number of threads.

Comment: can you develop or give some credit about your  assertion on 64 bit applications  ? 
+ "reasonable number of threads" , what does that mean for you. 
Thanks

Comment: Reasonable means on the same order as the number of logical cores. 64 bit apps typically have 48 bits of virtual memory space and the stacks can be larger than RAM size on most reasonable machines at this time.

Answer (score 3):

QThread stack size can be read and set by these two calls:

```
 uint QThread::stackSize() const
 void QThread::setStackSize(uint stackSize)
```

If Qthread is decade into OS specific thread in different OS, in linux pthread max stack size is 8M.

But sounds like you are concerned that QVector is growing in stack, this is not happening. QVector stores data in heap.

From source code of QVector,

```
void QVector<T>::append(const T &t)
{
     ...
    if (!isDetached() || isTooSmall) {
        ...
        reallocData(d->size, isTooSmall ? d->size + 1 : d->alloc, opt);
     ...
}
```

All it does it allocates new space in HEAP (pre-allocate predefined count of elements) and make sure data stored in continuous memory space. Doesn't looks like it concerns about page boundary etc.